# SheetJS json_to_sheet renaming headers

Tags: javascript, sheetjs

I have an array of objects. By default, sheet_to_json uses object keys as headers.
However, I need to rename those headers without explicitly modifying my array of objects.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 23):

I'm sharing the solution that I found

```
// Using same variables as the above answer
var Heading = [
  ["FirstName", "Last Name", "Email"],
];
var Data = [
  {firstName:"Jack", lastName: "Sparrow", email: "abc@example.com"},
  {firstName:"Harry", lastName: "Potter", email: "abc@example.com"},
];

//Had to create a new workbook and then add the header
const ws = XLSX.utils.book_new();
XLSX.utils.sheet_add_aoa(ws, Heading);

//Starting in the second row to avoid overriding and skipping headers
XLSX.utils.sheet_add_json(ws, Data, { origin: 'A2', skipHeader: true });
```

Comment: Remeber working with Apache POI in Java. This lib API is miles behind POI :/

Answer (score 18):

This code is based on [Angel Alvarez's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11329312/angel-alvarez-p%C3%A9rez) answer and added a working demo:

```
let arr = [
  { firstName: 'Jack', lastName: 'Sparrow', email: 'abc@example.com' },
  { firstName: 'Harry', lastName: 'Potter', email: 'abc@example.com' },
];

let Heading = [['FirstName', 'Last Name', 'Email']];

//Had to create a new workbook and then add the header
const wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();
const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet([]);
XLSX.utils.sheet_add_aoa(ws, Heading);

//Starting in the second row to avoid overriding and skipping headers
XLSX.utils.sheet_add_json(ws, arr, { origin: 'A2', skipHeader: true });

XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, 'Sheet1');

XLSX.writeFile(wb, 'filename.xlsx');
```

[STACKBLITZ DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/xlsx-json-to-sheet-gg26ec?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 14):

replace the last line with below.

```
XLSX.utils.sheet_add_json(ws, data, {skipHeader: true, origin: "A2"});
```

Answer (score 7):

i made this work around because both of the above approach were not working for me

```
let EXCEL_EXTENSION = '.xlsx';
     let worksheet: XLSX.WorkSheet;
     let customHeader = true;
      let sheetName = 'My Sheet 1';  
      
    if (customHeader) {  
     const headers: any = { Cust: 'Customer Name', Addr1: 'Address 1' };
    this.data.unshift(headers); // if custom header, then make sure first row of data is custom header 
      worksheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(json, { skipHeader: true });
    } else {
      worksheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(json);
    }
    const workbook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
    const fileName =  'myExcelFile_Export_' + moment().format('MM-DD-YYYY_hh:mm:ss').toString() + EXCEL_EXTENSION;
    XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(workbook, worksheet, sheetName);
    XLSX.writeFile(workbook, fileName);
```

Comment: Help would be appreciated if you can explain what this data here imply in the code --> 'this.data.unshift(headers)'

Comment: Array.prototype.unshift() javascript function will append the header at the front of the array of object. Therefore first row in array of object will be your header and remaining will be data row.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
var wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();

        var ws = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(json_data, { origin: 'A2', skipHeader: true });
        XLSX.utils.sheet_add_aoa(ws, headings); //heading: array of arrays

        XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws);


        XLSX.writeFile(wb, filename + '.xlsx')
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.